# Access for Shortcuts or Quickselection for Advanced Selection: new, extend, invert, intersect

Tags: 3d-view, interface, customization, shortcut, select

Is there an GUI way (e.g. Assign Shortcut) to have quick access to advances selection methods?
Or if not, is there an existing script or addon for this?

[image]

I'd like to get it into Hotkeys, PieMenus or QuickAccess.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

It's actually all in the keymap, except Invert Selection. So, I supplemented it.
[image]